# Becoming the subject of bad news

Tags: expressions

I'm looking for a term or saying with the meaning of becoming the subject of bad news.

In a sentence: "If you [do something bad], you risk becoming [the word or term I'm looking for]"

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "If you keep carrying on with the Mayor's spouse, you risk becoming **the talk of the town**.

Definition: A subject of considerable gossip, as in *Turning up drunk at the debutante ball will certainly make you the talk of the town.*

The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer. Houghton Mifflin Company.